# Material date-fns adapter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, date-fns

I'm currently switching from `Moment.js` to `date-fns` in my Angular app, but I'm facing an impediment.

I found as well an adapter made by angular `@angular/material-date-fns-adapter` and I added this in my material module:

```
{
    provide: DateAdapter,
    useClass: DateFnsAdapter,
    deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE],
},
{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DateHelpers.MatDateFormat }
```

and I'm getting the following error which I can't manage to solve:

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/material-date-fns-adapter/adapter/date-fns-adapter.d.ts:5:45 - error TS2314: Generic type 'DateAdapter<D>' requires 1 type argument(s).

5 export declare class DateFnsAdapter extends DateAdapter<Date, Locale> {
```

Is anyone who faced this issue or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue.

Root cause was me npm installing `@angular/material-date-fns-adapter` with a different version to the rest of angular/material.

It turns out, date-fns is not possible with my version of material, so I will try to upgrade the website to latest version of material. Wish me luck.

The angular material documentation website lets you select the version. Maybe it's the same for you.

Answer (score 1):

That means that when you are providing an adapter object (or a class) for the DateAdapter interface the D in the interface is manadatory... so you have to define D or say it is 'any' like so:

```
{
    provide: DateAdapter<any>,
    useClass: DateFnsAdapter,
    deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE],
},
```

that or `DateAdapter<undefined>` or even `DateAdapter<unknown>`
but the preferred thing would be to have strict typing like: `DateAdapter<MyInterfaceForDateAdapter>`

Answer (score 1):

To ensure proper configuration of `date-fns`, it is essential to establish the MAT_DATE_LOCALE injection token with a valid value sourced from the `date-fns` locales.

For instance:

```
import { DateFnsAdapter, MAT_DATE_FNS_FORMATS } from '@angular/material-date-fns-adapter';
import { es } from 'date-fns/locale';
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: es},
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: DateFnsAdapter,deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_DATE_FNS_FORMATS},
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppRootComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```